# В каком виде хранить данные в данном случае

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, веб-программирование

Ребят, всем привет. Есть небольшой сайт, на котором хочу сделать калькулятор. Проблема заключается в том, что калькулятор будет состоять из нескольких этапов:

1. Выбор типа коробки
2. Выбор размера коробки (зависит от типа коробки, т.е. для каждого типа свои размеры)
3. Выбор наполнения (Зависит от размера коробки, для каждого размера свои наполнения)

И так далее, всего 6-7 этапов. Проблема заключается в том, что писать огромную функцию, содержащую лишь "if - else if" очень не хочется.
Думал поступить следующим образом: сделать JSON файл, который будет хранить всю информацию, а оттуда она будет парситься через js. Вот только терзают меня сомнения, правильно ли я поступаю? Или же есть более рациональный способ?

Самое простое, что я думал сделать - это создать div'ы, которые буду открывать и скрывать, в зависимости от того, что выберет пользователь. Но тогда получается, что нужно создавать очень много divов, что может сказаться плохо на загрузке сайта, а это не есть хорошо.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что правильнее выбрать в данном случае?
Заранее спасибо! :)

Comment: Звучит как рулетка какая-то. Самое простое рещение и самое очевидное - используй базу данных и при выборе "коробки", подгружай нужные тебе данные.

Comment: Привет и тебе. Ты не даешь никаких числовых характеристик, поэтому сложно сказать, как оно будет работать. Например, "очень много divов" - это сколько примерно - сто, тысяча, десять тысяч?

Comment: @a-bobkov спасибо за ответ!)

Про данные:
Если хранить каждый вариант в отдельном DIV'е, то получится около 15-20 дивов.

Примерный вид данных в JSON, которые нужно будет постепенно выводить - https://jsfiddle.net/Alexxosipov/9nnszke8/

Comment: @Alexxosipov На мой взгляд, 15-20 дивов никак не повлияют на скорость загрузки страницы и лучше их сразу генерировать и показывать-скрывать по необходимости.